# Unify variable types of array elements

Tags: php, variable-types

After hours of debugging, I found an error in one of my scripts. For saving different event types in a database, I have an array of unique data for each event that can be used to identify the event.

So I basically have some code like

```
$key = md5(json_encode($data));
```

to generate a unique key for each event.

Now, in some cases, a value in the `$data` array is an integer, sometimes a string (depending on where it comes from - database or URL). That causes the outputs of `json_encode()` to be different from each other, though - once including quotes, once not.

Does anybody know a way to "unify" the variable types in the `$data` array? That would probably mean converting all strings that only contain an integer value to integer. Anything else I have to take care of when using `json_encode()`?

Comment: On a side note, most events in our database (obviously besides the incorrectly created ones) are now based on strings, so it might be better to convert the integers to strings instead of doing it the other way around.

Comment: i was thinking about suggesting that, if all you need is a consistent hash, but i wasnt sure what you were using it for...

Comment: Yes, I need a consistent hash, that's what it's about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_walk_recursive` combined with a function you have written to the effect of `maybe_intval` which performs the conversion you talk about on a single element.

EDIT: having read the documentation for `array_walk_recursive` more closely you'll actually want to write your own recursive function

```
function to_json($obj){
  if(is_object($obj))
    $obj=(array)$obj;
  if(is_array($obj))
    return array_map('to_json',$obj);
  return "$obj"; // or return is_int($obj)?intval($obj):$obj; 
}
```

Comment: Why not `array_walk_recursive`, though?

Comment: Ok, I used `array_map` (recursion isn't needed) with a simple int-to-string conversion function. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: `array_walk_recursive` as far as i can tell won't let you modify the original object or keep track of any nested structure - you can just e.g. print it. If you have no nested structures `array_map` will do